# What's the meaning of the headers when adding a CSV::Row to a CSV::Table in Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, csv, fastercsv

I am trying to add a row to a CSV::Table in Ruby 1.9 (the questions also applies to FasterCSV in Ruby 1.8). If the order of the columns is different in the new row than in the table, the elements are added to the wrong columns, even if the headers are correctly specified. It looks as if the headers in the new row are ignored.

```
require 'csv'

first_row = CSV::Row.new(["h1","h2","h3"],[1,2,3])
second_row = CSV::Row.new(["h2","h1","h3"],[2,1,3]) # note the change in order
table = CSV::Table.new([first_row])
table << second_row
puts table.to_s
```

Output:

```
h1,h2,h3
1,2,3
2,1,3
```

But since I am specifying the headers explicitly, I would expect CSV to match the headers of the new row to those of the table and produce this output:

```
h1,h2,h3
1,2,3
1,2,3
```

Any explanations? Can I do something about it other than reordering the columns myself before creating a new row?

Answer (score 0):

The explanation in the source code CSV::Table#to_csv.

I'm novice in Ruby, but try my patch:

```
--- csv.rb.old  2011-07-18 23:24:38.184913108 +0600
+++ csv.rb  2011-07-18 23:23:54.972802099 +0600
@@ -836,7 +836,7 @@
         if row.header_row?
           rows
         else
-            rows + [row.fields.to_csv(options)]
+            rows + [row.fields(*headers).to_csv(options)]
         end
       end.join
     end
```

Output:

```
h1,h2,h3
1,2,3
1,2,3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot scuawn, your patch works nicely. See also my comment to Davids answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [scuawn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734755/whats-the-meaning-of-the-headers-when-adding-a-csvrow-to-a-csvtable-in-ruby/6736807#6736807), CSV::Table#to_csv method does not work as you are expecting.

However data in CSV::Table *are* placed in proper columns ! Based on your example, you may see that's true:

```
irb(main):1:0> table.entries
=> [#<CSV::Row "h1":1 "h2":2 "h3":3>, #<CSV::Row "h2":2 "h1":1 "h3":3>]
irb(main):2:0> table.headers
=> ["h1", "h2", "h3"]
irb(main):3:0> table.values_at(*table.headers)
=> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. However, I now think that the CSV::Table is just a collection of CSV::Rows with no strict notion of columns. The correct ordering into columns happens when you call values_at(). If you use table.by_col[0] to get the first column you still get [1,2] instead of [1,1].

Comment: I'd agree there is a flaw in #to_csv code or even in #<< method which could immediately store rows ordered by the header.